# Are there legitimate methods other than feats for an erudite to learn powers not on the psion/wilder list?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

An Erudite can select powers freely from the psion/wilder lists, and from all the discipline lists with certain caveats.

A StP alternate class feature Erudite can learn spells, converting them to "spellpowers" with the same caveats as discipline powers; they count as powers.

The Expanded Knowledge or the Hidden Talent feat clearly allows the acquisition of any one power from any list, with certain caveats.

---

Are there any non feat methods which legitimately allow an Erudite to acquire other non-psion/wilder powers (Lurk powers, Leech powers, mantle powers, etc.)?

Please do not include anything involving Manipulate Form, or similar levels of TO.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### Independent Research

Expanded Psionics Handbook, p64. By spending one week and 200 XP per level of power, plus a Psicraft check at the end, any kind of manifester can create a new power, or duplicate an existing one. If the check fails, the process can be repeated by spending more time and XP. This method apparently allows one to make class versions of non class powers.

Note that this option requires DM permission and approval.

---

#### Favored Erudite Alternate Class Feature:

A Favored Erudite who has used one or two of their 1st level bonus feats to take the *Favored Discipline* alternate class feature gains the ability to have all powers of a given discipline as general Psion/Wilder powers for the purposes of learning, regardless of what class list they are on.

Thus so long as a power has a discipline type, then it could potentially be learned as a class list power.

While the ACF in question happens to require a feat in payment for the ability, ACFs are not feats being instead class features.

Answer (score 6):

*Psychic Chirurgery* (from XPH) can teach any psionic power to any psionic character, explicitly bypassing class lists. It's a 9th-level telepathy-discipline-specific power with a hefty xp cost. (Though the discipline part isn't all that restrictive, since one can use Psychic Chirurgery to teach Psychic Chirurgery itself to a non-telepath.)

> Transfer Knowledge: If desired, you can use this power to directly transfer knowledge of a power you know to another psionic character. You can give a character knowledge of a power of any level that she can manifest, even if the power is not normally on the character’s power list. Knowledge of powers gained through psychic chirurgery does not count toward the maximum number of powers a character can know
>   per level.

If you have access to the components but they aren't all in the same person, e.g. if the person who knows Psychic Chirurgery wants to learn rather than teach, then you can combine it with *Metaconcert*. This temporarily creates a psionic hive-mind which knows all the powers of all of the participants; the hive-mind can then manifest Psychic Chirurgery (borrowed from one person) to teach another power (borrowed from a different person) to the former or to someone else entirely.